# Editing a loop to show additional images

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm sure this is straightforward but I don't have a lot of experience with php.

The following code puts 3 boxes across a page that are fed from the posts with a certain category. What I want to do it make it put 6 boxes across the page - a line of 3 then another line of 3 underneath. I changes the 'posts_per_page' =>' line to six and while it allows for 6 posts to be showed the last image falls on a 3rd line sort of like this:

X X X

X X

X

Any idea how to make it work?

Thanks!

```
<?php
$args = array(
             'category_name' => 'cafe',
     'post__not_in' => $slider_arr,
           'post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page' => 3
             //'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
             );
query_posts($args);
$x = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if($x == 2) { ?>
<div class="home_blog_box home_blog_box_last">
<?php } elseif($x == 1) { ?>
<div class="home_blog_box home_second_blog_box">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="home_blog_box">
<?php } ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-blog'); ?></a>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</div><!--//home_blog_box-->    
<?php $x++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: do you have a link to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting `$x` to `-1` once it reaches `2` (-1 because of the default increment at the end). The last item never gets the css class `home_blog_box_last` because `$x` just keeps increasing.

```
<?php if($x == 2) { ?>
<div class="home_blog_box home_blog_box_last">
<?php $x = -1;
} elseif($x == 1) { ?>
<div class="home_blog_box home_second_blog_box">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="home_blog_box">
<?php } ?>
```

Also, this causes a problem (though you don't see it) on your second box in the middle row because it doesn't get the css class you think it does neither.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for taking time to explain the solution. Much appreciated!